# IOS8 - [UIlabel sizeToFit] causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS crash

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uilabel, exc-bad-access, sizetofit

Our users are experiencing recurring crashes in the method below.  The crashes happen always in the one of the lines: `[lbl sizeToFit]` (the `lbl` variable is re-initialized and reused. to my understanding, this should not cause any issues).

These crashes happen only on iOS8 (same method was used for a very long time on ios7 without any issues). I could not recreate this crash my self.
Currently, my only lead is from the 'sizeToFit' apple documentation:

> ..In some cases, if a view does not have a superview, it may size itself to the screen bounds. Thus, if you want a given view to size itself to its parent view, you should add it to the parent view before calling this method.

However, I don't see how this can generate bad memory refrences.

```
-(void)setUpHeaders:(NSInteger)fortype{
    headers = [NSMutableArray array];
    if(fortype == GROUP_BY_TIME){

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        UIView* header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 68)];
        header.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [headers addObject:header];
    }

    int today = (int)[NSDate dayOfTheWeekOfDate:[NSDate date]];
    int firstDayOfTheWeek = (int)[defaults integerForKey:FIRST_DAY_IF_THE_WEEK_KEY];
    NSString* restOfTheWeek = nil;
    if(today == ((firstDayOfTheWeek + 4) % 7) + 1) restOfTheWeek = MyLocalizedString(@"THE COMING WEEK", @"THE COMING WEEK") ;
    else if(today == ((firstDayOfTheWeek + 5) % 7) + 1) restOfTheWeek = MyLocalizedString(@"REST OF NEXT WEEK", @"REST OF NEXT WEEK") ;
    else restOfTheWeek = MyLocalizedString(@"REST OF THE WEEK", @"REST OF THE WEEK") ;

    UILabel* lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 38, 300, 30)];
    lbl.tag = 22;
    lbl.font = XX_LARGE_VOLKS_FONT;
    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    [lbl setText:MyLocalizedString(@"TODAY", @"TODAY") ];
    [lbl sizeToFit];
    [[headers objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:lbl];

    lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([MyLocalizedString(@"TODAY", @"TODAY") sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Volkswagen-Serial-Medium-Regular" size:21]].width + 15, 41, 300, 30)];
    lbl.tag = 2;
    lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Volkswagen-Regular" size:19];
    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [lbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@, %@ %d  ",[[[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier] containSubString:@"he"] ? [[[NSDate date] dayOfTheWeekString] uppercaseString] : [[[NSDate date] threeLetterDayOfTheWeekString] uppercaseString],[NSDate abbriviatedMonthForDate:[NSDate date]],(int)[components day]]];
    lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [lbl sizeToFit];
    [[headers objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:lbl];

    UIImageView *img;
    img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 67, 320, 1)];
    [img setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    img.alpha = 0.5;
    img.tag = 3;
    [[headers objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:img];

    img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(lbl.frame.origin.x+2, 40, 1, 19)];
    [img setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    img.alpha = 0.5;
    img.tag = 33;
    [[headers objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:img];

    lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 38, 300, 30)];
    lbl.tag = 22;
    lbl.font = XX_LARGE_VOLKS_FONT;
    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    [lbl setText:MyLocalizedString(@"TOMORROW", @"TOMORROW")];
    [lbl sizeToFit];
    [[headers objectAtIndex:1] addSubview:lbl];

    lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([MyLocalizedString(@"TOMORROW", @"TOMORROW") sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Volkswagen-Serial-Medium-Regular" size:21]].width + 15, 41, 200, 30)];
    lbl.tag = 2;
    lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Volkswagen-Regular" size:19];
    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:86400]];
    [lbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@, %@ %d  ",[[[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier] containSubString:@"he"] ? [[[[NSDate date] dateByAddingDays:1] dayOfTheWeekString] uppercaseString] : [[[[NSDate date] dateByAddingDays:1] threeLetterDayOfTheWeekString] uppercaseString],[NSDate abbriviatedMonthForDate:[[NSDate date] dateByAddingDays:1]],(int)[components day]]];
    lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    [lbl sizeToFit];
    [[headers objectAtIndex:1] addSubview:lbl];

    img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 67, 320, 1)];
    [img setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    img.alpha = 0.5;
    img.tag = 3;
    [[headers objectAtIndex:1] addSubview:img];

    img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(lbl.frame.origin.x+2, 40, 1, 19)];
    [img setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    img.alpha = 0.5;
    img.tag = 33;
    [[headers objectAtIndex:1] addSubview:img];

    lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 38, 300, 30)];
    lbl.tag = 2;
    lbl.font = XX_LARGE_VOLKS_FONT;
    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    [lbl setText:restOfTheWeek];
    [[headers objectAtIndex:2] addSubview:lbl];

    img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 67, 320, 1)];
    [img setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    img.alpha = 0.5;
    img.tag = 3;
    [[headers objectAtIndex:2] addSubview:img];

    lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 38, 300, 30)];
    lbl.tag = 2;
    lbl.font = XX_LARGE_VOLKS_FONT;
    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    [lbl setText:MyLocalizedString(@"LATER", @"LATER")];
    [[headers objectAtIndex:3] addSubview:lbl];

    img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 67, 320, 1)];
    [img setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    img.alpha = 0.5;
    img.tag = 3;
    [[headers objectAtIndex:3] addSubview:img];

    lbl = (UILabel*)[[headers objectAtIndex:0] viewWithTag:2];
    todayWeather = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(lbl.frame.size.width + lbl.frame.origin.x-5, 38, 30, 25)];
    [[headers objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:todayWeather];

    lbl = (UILabel*)[[headers objectAtIndex:1] viewWithTag:2];
    tomorrowWeather = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(lbl.frame.size.width + lbl.frame.origin.x-5, 38, 30, 25)];
    [[headers objectAtIndex:1] addSubview:tomorrowWeather];

    [self gotWeather];

}
else{
    NSMutableArray* labels = [[self getLabels] valueForKey:@"values"];

    CGRect headerFrame, labelFrame, seperatorFrame;
    if ([defaults integerForKey:DISPLAY_TYPE]==DisplayTypeNotes) {
        headerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60);
         labelFrame = CGRectMake(10, 30, 300, 30);
        seperatorFrame = CGRectMake(0, 59, 320, 1);
    }else{
        headerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 68);
        labelFrame = CGRectMake(10, 38, 300, 30);
        seperatorFrame = CGRectMake(0, 67, 320, 1);

    }


    for(int i=0;i<[labels count];i++){
        UIView* header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:headerFrame];
        header.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        UILabel* lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
        lbl.tag = 2;
        lbl.font = XX_LARGE_VOLKS_FONT;
        [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
        [lbl setText:[labels objectAtIndex:i]];
        [header addSubview:lbl];

        UIImageView *img;
        img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:seperatorFrame];
        [img setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
        img.alpha = 0.5;
        img.tag = 3;
        [header addSubview:img];

        [header bringSubviewToFront:lbl];

        [headers addObject:header];
    }
    //add aditonale header for unlabeled tasks\notes    
    UIView* header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:headerFrame];
    header.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UILabel* lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
    lbl.tag = 2;
    lbl.font = XX_LARGE_VOLKS_FONT;
    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    [lbl setText:MyLocalizedString(@"Not Labeled", @"Not Labeled")];
    [header addSubview:lbl];

    UIImageView *img;
    img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:seperatorFrame];
    [img setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    img.alpha = 0.5;
    img.tag = 3;
    [header addSubview:img];

    [headers insertObject:header atIndex:0];

  }


}

Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  UIKit                          0x000000018c4f22a0 -[_UIViewAdditiveAnimationAction runActionForKey:object:arguments:] + 640
1  UIKit                          0x000000018c4f228c -[_UIViewAdditiveAnimationAction runActionForKey:object:arguments:] + 620
2  QuartzCore                     0x000000018bb80198 CA::Layer::set_bounds(CA::Rect const&, bool) + 408
3  QuartzCore                     0x000000018bb7ff78 -[CALayer setBounds:] + 104
4  UIKit                          0x000000018c70fa50 -[_UILabelLayer setBounds:] + 56
5  QuartzCore                     0x000000018bb80c58 -[CALayer setFrame:] + 488
6  UIKit                          0x000000018c70f9e4 -[_UILabelLayer setFrame:] + 56
7  UIKit                          0x000000018c22de0c -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 292
8  UIKit                          0x000000018c23d69c -[UILabel setFrame:] + 140
9  UIKit                          0x000000018c23ea88 -[UIView(Geometry) sizeToFit] + 248
10 24me                           0x00000001001e292c -[ViewController setUpHeaders:] (ViewController.m:3412)
11 24me                           0x00000001001dfcac -[ViewController groupByTime] (ViewController.m:3146)
12 24me                           0x00000001001df6a0 -[ViewController group] (ViewController.m:3071)
13 Foundation                     0x0000000188970ea8 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 424
14 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000187a6a210 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
15 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000187a69ec0 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 888
16 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000187a6790c __CFRunLoopRun + 1372
17 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000187995664 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
18 GraphicsServices               0x0000000190acf5a4 GSEventRunModal + 168
19 UIKit                          0x000000018c29a4f8 UIApplicationMain + 1488
20 24me                           0x00000001000642bc main (main.m:16)
21 libdyld.dylib                  0x000000019875ea08 start + 4
```

Comment: Got similar issue with sizeToFit in iOS8: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=x52)

Comment: Ever find anything else about this?

Comment: Have you tried making sure it's running on the main thread? I'm sure I ran into a similar problem recently but not 100% so don't want to post as an answer.

Comment: Have you considered exchanging addSubview and sizeToFit to following? Then it'd match what apple says in docs. 

[[headers objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:lbl];

[lbl sizeToFit];


As far as EXC_BAD_ACCESS, most of apple code still runs MRC (pre-ARC), so it is easy to run int EXC_BAD_ACCESS due to assign pointers.

Comment: If your application is multithreaded, you could try using this tool in order to detect if your code uses UIKit from a secondary thread. If it does, then you will know precisely at which moment and you can fix that problem. https://gist.github.com/steipete/5664345

Comment: Try using '- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size;'

Comment: Are you sure it's the size to fit? That holding array doesn't look initialised correctly to me. Alloc init?? Breakpoint on the line containing "[[headers objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:lbl];" and if it doesn't crash there is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I modified a bit of your code and added comment. Take note of the highlighted part.

```
-(void)setUpHeaders:(NSInteger)fortype{
    headers = [NSMutableArray array];
    if(fortype == GROUP_BY_TIME){

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        UIView* header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 68)];
        header.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [headers addObject:header];
    }

    int today = (int)[NSDate dayOfTheWeekOfDate:[NSDate date]];
    int firstDayOfTheWeek = (int)[defaults integerForKey:FIRST_DAY_IF_THE_WEEK_KEY];
    NSString* restOfTheWeek = nil;
    if(today == ((firstDayOfTheWeek + 4) % 7) + 1) restOfTheWeek = MyLocalizedString(@"THE COMING WEEK", @"THE COMING WEEK") ;
    else if(today == ((firstDayOfTheWeek + 5) % 7) + 1) restOfTheWeek = MyLocalizedString(@"REST OF NEXT WEEK", @"REST OF NEXT WEEK") ;
    else restOfTheWeek = MyLocalizedString(@"REST OF THE WEEK", @"REST OF THE WEEK") ;

    UILabel* lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 38, 300, 30)];
    lbl.tag = 22;
    lbl.font = XX_LARGE_VOLKS_FONT;
    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    [lbl setText:MyLocalizedString(@"TODAY", @"TODAY") ];
```

> [[headers objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:lbl]; // take note of this part
>   [lbl sizeToFit]; // always add view to its parent before calling 'sizeToFit' or it will crash

```
    lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([MyLocalizedString(@"TODAY", @"TODAY") sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Volkswagen-Serial-Medium-Regular" size:21]].width + 15, 41, 300, 30)];
    lbl.tag = 2;
    lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Volkswagen-Regular" size:19];
    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [lbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@, %@ %d  ",[[[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier] containSubString:@"he"] ? [[[NSDate date] dayOfTheWeekString] uppercaseString] : [[[NSDate date] threeLetterDayOfTheWeekString] uppercaseString],[NSDate abbriviatedMonthForDate:[NSDate date]],(int)[components day]]];
    lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

> [[headers objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:lbl]; // take note of this part
>   [lbl sizeToFit]; // always add view to its parent before calling 'sizeToFit' or it will crash

```
    UIImageView *img;
    img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 67, 320, 1)];
    [img setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    img.alpha = 0.5;
    img.tag = 3;
    [[headers objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:img];

    img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(lbl.frame.origin.x+2, 40, 1, 19)];
    [img setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    img.alpha = 0.5;
    img.tag = 33;
    [[headers objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:img];

    lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 38, 300, 30)];
    lbl.tag = 22;
    lbl.font = XX_LARGE_VOLKS_FONT;
    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    [lbl setText:MyLocalizedString(@"TOMORROW", @"TOMORROW")];
```

> [[headers objectAtIndex:1] addSubview:lbl];  // take note of this part
>   [lbl sizeToFit]; // always add view to its parent before calling 'sizeToFit' or it will crash

```
    lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([MyLocalizedString(@"TOMORROW", @"TOMORROW") sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Volkswagen-Serial-Medium-Regular" size:21]].width + 15, 41, 200, 30)];
    lbl.tag = 2;
    lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Volkswagen-Regular" size:19];
    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:86400]];
    [lbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@, %@ %d  ",[[[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier] containSubString:@"he"] ? [[[[NSDate date] dateByAddingDays:1] dayOfTheWeekString] uppercaseString] : [[[[NSDate date] dateByAddingDays:1] threeLetterDayOfTheWeekString] uppercaseString],[NSDate abbriviatedMonthForDate:[[NSDate date] dateByAddingDays:1]],(int)[components day]]];
    lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

> [[headers objectAtIndex:1] addSubview:lbl]; // take note of this part
>   [lbl sizeToFit]; // always add view to its parent before calling 'sizeToFit' or it will crash

```
    img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 67, 320, 1)];
    [img setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    img.alpha = 0.5;
    img.tag = 3;
    [[headers objectAtIndex:1] addSubview:img];

    img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(lbl.frame.origin.x+2, 40, 1, 19)];
    [img setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    img.alpha = 0.5;
    img.tag = 33;
    [[headers objectAtIndex:1] addSubview:img];

    lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 38, 300, 30)];
    lbl.tag = 2;
    lbl.font = XX_LARGE_VOLKS_FONT;
    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    [lbl setText:restOfTheWeek];

    [[headers objectAtIndex:2] addSubview:lbl];

    img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 67, 320, 1)];
    [img setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    img.alpha = 0.5;
    img.tag = 3;
    [[headers objectAtIndex:2] addSubview:img];

    lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 38, 300, 30)];
    lbl.tag = 2;
    lbl.font = XX_LARGE_VOLKS_FONT;
    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    [lbl setText:MyLocalizedString(@"LATER", @"LATER")];
    [[headers objectAtIndex:3] addSubview:lbl];

    img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 67, 320, 1)];
    [img setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    img.alpha = 0.5;
    img.tag = 3;
    [[headers objectAtIndex:3] addSubview:img];

    lbl = (UILabel*)[[headers objectAtIndex:0] viewWithTag:2];
    todayWeather = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(lbl.frame.size.width + lbl.frame.origin.x-5, 38, 30, 25)];
    [[headers objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:todayWeather];

    lbl = (UILabel*)[[headers objectAtIndex:1] viewWithTag:2];
    tomorrowWeather = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(lbl.frame.size.width + lbl.frame.origin.x-5, 38, 30, 25)];
    [[headers objectAtIndex:1] addSubview:tomorrowWeather];

    [self gotWeather];

}
else{
    NSMutableArray* labels = [[self getLabels] valueForKey:@"values"];

    CGRect headerFrame, labelFrame, seperatorFrame;
    if ([defaults integerForKey:DISPLAY_TYPE]==DisplayTypeNotes) {
        headerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60);
         labelFrame = CGRectMake(10, 30, 300, 30);
        seperatorFrame = CGRectMake(0, 59, 320, 1);
    }else{
        headerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 68);
        labelFrame = CGRectMake(10, 38, 300, 30);
        seperatorFrame = CGRectMake(0, 67, 320, 1);

    }


    for(int i=0;i<[labels count];i++){
        UIView* header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:headerFrame];
        header.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        UILabel* lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
        lbl.tag = 2;
        lbl.font = XX_LARGE_VOLKS_FONT;
        [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
        [lbl setText:[labels objectAtIndex:i]];
        [header addSubview:lbl];

        UIImageView *img;
        img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:seperatorFrame];
        [img setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
        img.alpha = 0.5;
        img.tag = 3;
        [header addSubview:img];

        [header bringSubviewToFront:lbl];

        [headers addObject:header];
    }
    //add aditonale header for unlabeled tasks\notes    
    UIView* header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:headerFrame];
    header.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UILabel* lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
    lbl.tag = 2;
    lbl.font = XX_LARGE_VOLKS_FONT;
    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    [lbl setText:MyLocalizedString(@"Not Labeled", @"Not Labeled")];
    [header addSubview:lbl];

    UIImageView *img;
    img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:seperatorFrame];
    [img setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    img.alpha = 0.5;
    img.tag = 3;
    [header addSubview:img];

    [headers insertObject:header atIndex:0];

  }
}
```